# Creating TSQL query displaying a cumulative weekly breakdown for a date range?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting, cumulative-sum

I want to provide begin and end date to a proc that will display a cumulative breakdown for each week. For example, I entered a begin date: 3/30/2013 and end date: 8/10/2013

```
Week            Cumulative  Imported    Cumulative Assigned
3/30/2013   22,148                      21,123
4/6/2013    29,420                      27,142
4/13/2013   48,309                      44,585
4/20/2013   49,342                      44,997
4/27/2013   127,321                     59,873
5/4/2013    154,556                     114,749
5/11/2013   195,403                     177,383
5/18/2013   222,800                     201,242
5/25/2013   347,479                     242,050
6/1/2013    384,110                     242,729
6/8/2013    384,110                     273,810
6/15/2013   393,744                     296,156
6/22/2013   395,167                     297,873
6/29/2013   448,639                     303,001
7/6/2013    448,639                     315,404
7/13/2013   469,906                     321,247
7/20/2013   475,221                     351,044
7/27/2013   481,554                     377,717
8/3/2013    488,299                     378,643
8/10/2013   498,280                     408,801
```

**Here is my stab at the Query, How do I modify my query to look like my example above?**

```
SELECT
    IDOC.IDOC_ID,
    FI.Name,
    IDOC.Import_Date,
    DATEADD(week, datediff(day, '20000109', IDOC.Import_Date)/7, '20000109') as IMPORTweekstart,
    ISNULL(ITA.Assigned_Date, '1/1/1900') as Assigned_Date,
    ISNULL(DATEADD(week, datediff(day, '20000109', ITA.Assigned_Date)/7, '20000109'), '1/1/1900') as ASSIGNweekstart
    FROM IDOC 
        JOIN File_Type FI 
            on IDOC.File_Type_ID=FI.File_Type_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IDOC_Team_Assignment ITA 
            ON IDOC.IDOC_ID=ITA.IDOC_ID
 WHERE ITA.Assigned_Date BETWEEN '03/30/2013' and '08/10/2013'
```

The output:

```
IDOC_ID   Name          Import_Date     Import_wkStart  Assigned_Date   Assign_wkStart
1     TE Input  2014-05-23  2014-05-18  2014-05-01  2014-04-27
```

Comment: How do I modify my query to look like my example above?

Comment: Can you clarify what `Cumulative Imported` and `Cumulative Assigned` aggregate? Difficult to answer an ambiguous question.

Comment: The aggregate would be Sum(Import_Date) and Sum(Assigned_Date). Not sure how to list all weeks within 3/30 and 8/10.

Comment: And list the Sum total within each week.

Comment: Alright give me a min I got you covered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this should be a fairly straightforward query, make changes as needed. When you set up your proc you can specify the from and to dates to be carried from the proc parameters into the variables.

```
SET @from_date = '2013-03-30';    
SET @to_date = '2013-08-10';    


SELECT     
    DATEADD(week, datediff(day, '20000109', IDOC.Import_Date)/7, '20000109') as IMPORTweekstart,    
    COUNT(SELECT ITA.IDOC_ID WHERE ITA.Assigned_Date <= @from_date),    
    COUNT(SELECT ITA.IDOC_ID WHERE ITA.Assigned_Date <= @to_date)    

FROM IDOC     
INNER JOIN File_Type FI     
        on IDOC.File_Type_ID = FI.File_Type_ID    
INNER JOIN JOIN IDOC_Team_Assignment ITA    
    ON IDOC.IDOC_ID=ITA.IDOC_ID    

GROUP BY IMPORTweekstart;
```

Comment: Or something along those lines, you get the idea.